# Reverse dns using dns server of domain

Tags: dns

I need to check a reverse dns using the DNS servers of some domains. But I'm having some problems.

```
dig -x 212.26.146.21 +short
mx20.gypost.com.
```

all ok

```
dig -x 212.26.146.21 @8.8.8.8 +short
mx20.gypost.com.
```

its ok too

```
dig SOA google.com +short 
ns1.google.com. dns-admin.google.com. 2014021800 7200 1800 1209600 300

dig -x 212.26.146.21 @ns1.google.com +short
```

empty

I can't find reverse address using NS record of any domain. What i do wrong? And how i can check my reverse address using dns server of gmx.com, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for reverse DNS records is other dns-servers then for not reverse. You can look full dns mechanism by command:

```
$ dig -x 212.26.146.21 +trace
```

And easy way for get dns-server which you need:

```
$ dig -x 212.26.146.21 PTR
```

See `AUTHORITY SECTION`:

```
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
146.26.212.in-addr.arpa. 172799 IN  NS  ns2.adamant.net.
146.26.212.in-addr.arpa. 172799 IN  NS  ns2.lucky.net.
146.26.212.in-addr.arpa. 172799 IN  NS  ns2.iptcom.net.
146.26.212.in-addr.arpa. 172799 IN  NS  ns.adamant.net.
```

Then:

```
$ dig -x 212.26.146.21 +short @ns2.lucky.net.
mx20.gypost.com.
```

Comment: Some domains can't send mails to my domain. I can't now add log but there some like "cant find reverse dns". How i can find dns server of some domain then?

Comment: You must know the IP from which your server sends emails. Also you must know helo string, which your mail server sends to others in SMTP protocol. And you must ask your provider, which give you IP for he set PTR on this IP to your hostname. Also you must set A record for this helo to right IP.

Comment: In other words, resolving IP->hostname must be the same as reversed hostname->IP, and this hostname must be set as helo/ehlo string in your mail server.

Comment: The fact is that sometimes only letters do not reach. And only some domains. For example, no problem with google.

Comment: Because only some mail servers check this fact and reject emails from IP which has not reverse dns.

Comment: "450 4.7.1 Client host rejected: cannot find your hostname, [212.26.146.21]"

from gmx.com domain. But PTR and MX records is ok on my domain.(gypost.com)

Comment: What is helo/ehlo string your server sends to other mail servers? Also, this can be temporal resolving problems (internet connectivity troubles or something else).

Comment: mail.gypost.com HELO

kostyuk@gypost.com